# How to check weather the Variable includes number alphabet or character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a program in JavaScript for password strength calculator so i need 3 function.
One function tells whether the varaible passed has Alphabet or not and same check for Numeric and Characters

```js
var = 'abc123'

function alpha(var) {
  // Should return true if variable includes alphabet and false if not
}

function Num(var) {
  // Should return true if variable includes Numeric value and false if not
}

function SpecialChar(var) {
  // Should return true if variable includes any Special Character and false if not
}
```

I have tried this method

```js
var password = 'abc123'

function alpha() {
  return password.match(/^[a-zA-Z- ]+$/) ? true : false
}

function num() {
  return password.match(/^[0-9]+$/)
}
```

but this not works as i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of match i suggest using [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) it will return true or false based on the given expression.

Second of all you are using `^` and `$` which mean the start and end of the string. If you remove them your regex works. The reason we don't need them is because right now you're saying "I need atleast one alphanumeric character between the start and the end of the string, **nothing else**". Same goes for the second function but then with numbers instead of alphanumeric characters

```js
var password = 'abc123'

function hasAlpha(str){
  return /[a-zA-Z- ]+/.test(str);
}
function hasNum(str){
  return /[0-9]+/.test(str);
}

console.log(hasAlpha(password));
console.log(hasNum(password));
```

Answer (score 0):

what if you try following regex instead ?

`/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})/`

this will match for password strength which i guess you are looking for.